# R: created an object with two properties (class?)

Tags: r, object

I develop a project on several computers, and paths to scripts and data depend on which computer I develop.

So I would like to create different objects, one for each possible developing environment. Each object would have two properties: projectPath and dataPath, where I would store those respective paths (as strings).

I would precreate each object. 
Then at the beginning of the script, I would simply like to say something like:

```
devEnvironment <- PersonalLaptop
```

and the script would define variables later used in other scripts, e.g.

```
data.path <- devEnvironment[dataPath]
```

I'm sure this is fairly easy to do, maybe just a case of creating a class and one instance for each developing environment, but I am a bit of a beginner and this is all fairly new to me...

Comment: I'm suspect most of this could be solved better by building a package.

Answer (score 0):

Creating objects

```
PersonalLaptop <- list(projectPath="laptop/project/path",  dataPath="laptop/data/path")
Computer <- list(projectPath="computer/project/path",  dataPath="computer/data/path")
```

Using the object

```
devEnvironment <- PersonalLaptop

data.path <- devEnvironment$dataPath
data.path
```

I hope this is that you expected. Best regards.